# Magento 2 checkout can not load always spinning

Tags: magento2, checkout

Magento 2 **local development installation is working fine**, when place a order and  resulting in **an endless spinning wheel load screen in checkout page**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you please let me know details about how to do the deploy?
Thanks in advance. Best regards Jack

Answer (score 0):

As per as, your screenshot

**At checkout page has some some js error, Seems responsive.sj is not load at checkout page and it showing 404.**

*I guess that you need to do a static content deploy.May it will resolved the issue.*

Answer (score 0):

Here Magento complains that it looks for a js module `Magento_Theme/js/repsonsive` and could not found it.

So you need to make sure you have following file in your theme section: `app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/view/frontend/web/js/responsive.js`. If the file does exists, then you need to perform a static content deployment. For that: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

Note: The path for the js file given above may vary depend upon you theme.